# How to send notifications to end users in SharePoint if a field is not empty using the workflow?

Tags: sharepoint

How to send notifications to end users in SharePoint if a field is not empty using the workflow ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following steps:

1. Create SharePoint Designer workflow on your list
   (set this workflow to fire on Item Creation)
2. Write below condition 
   (Note : Here I have used 'Title' field to be checked for non empty condition. Please replace this with your field/column name on which you want to check for non empty value)

   [image]
3. Publish this workflow